# Как повернуть звездолет по оси x, чтобы он поворачивался туда, куда смотрит мышка?

Tags: unity3d, move

Кораблик может лететь прямо, а также делать "бочку", но мне также нужно что бы он с помощью мышки поворачивался по оси x  , при этом чтобы поворот ограничивался шириной экрана(чтобы нельзя было улететь назад). Я пытался кок-что сделать, но получалась деградация, а также кораблик переставал переворачиватся. Помогите пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Мало информации. Как уровень выглядит? Прямой бесконечный коридор, по которому движется корабль или что-то другое? Если прямой коридор и нужно просто запретить полет назад, то можно ограничить поворот корабля по осям х и у на 90 градусов и тогда он не сможет лететь назад.

Comment: @KOTIK бесконечный коридор с шипами. Надо чтобы он поворачивал влево вправо и все. Все остальное есть уже